# Film Category vs. City On SAKILA DATABASE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Can Someone help me with the SQL code for:

Write a query to find the number of occurrences of each film_category in each city. Arrange them in the decreasing order of their category count.

I tried something like this but I am able to see count of few cities only.

```
    SELECT 
    name, city, COUNT(city) AS category_count
FROM
    category
        INNER JOIN
    film_category USING (category_id)
        INNER JOIN
    film USING (film_id)
        INNER JOIN
    inventory USING (film_id)
        INNER JOIN
    store USING (store_id)
        INNER JOIN
    address USING (address_id)
        INNER JOIN
    city USING (city_id)
GROUP BY name , city
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC;
```

Comment: Pretend we don't know what Sakila is.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the output corresponding to that data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    name, city, COUNT(city) AS category_count
FROM
    category
    JOIN film_category USING (category_id)
    JOIN inventory USING (film_id)
    JOIN store USING (store_id)
    JOIN address USING (address_id)
    JOIN city USING (city_id)
GROUP BY name, city
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC;
```

One way you could do this is to remove the join on the film category and directly join film_category and inventory on category_id.  Also the `INNER` reserved word is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Write a query to find the number of occurrences of each film_category in each city. Arrange them in the decreasing order of their category count.

```
 SELECT name, city, COUNT(category_id) AS category_count
 FROM category
 INNER JOIN film_category
 USING (category_id)
 INNER JOIN inventory
 USING(film_id)
 INNER JOIN store
 USING (store_id)
 INNER JOIN address
 USING (address_id)
 INNER JOIN city
 USING (city_id)
 GROUP BY name, city
 ORDER BY category_count DESC;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?